# Posting to Ruby on Rails JSON PUT

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to post to the following method /users.json

**Here's my code in Ruby on Rails**

```
# POST /users
# POST /users.json

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and inside my user params

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
end
```

**I am using chrome Advanced REST client to post** (http://postimg.org/image/fphun12fx/)

[image http://postimg.org/image/fphun12fx/](http://postimg.org/image/fphun12fx/)

Rails kept giving me error stating param not found :user, how do I create the param for user?

Also, if we have the parameter :user, does it mean for jQuery ajax, I would have to do something like the below?

data: { user: {name: xx, password: xx, password_confirmation: xx} }

Comment: it will work if I do the following params.permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar) but I'm just curious how do we solve the .require(:user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)` as strong parameters that means you should nest your params under 'user' key, i.e. your params hash should look something like this:

```
{ "user"=>{"name"=>"name", "password"=>"password"} }
```

So, on your form simply use rails form builders or if you use a form_tag then nest attributes under the 'user' key.

Comment: I am more interested in sending through a post request using Advance REST Client or javascript ajax calls instead of using rails form_builder or form_tag which isn't as issue.

Comment: Well, doesn't matter which one to use, all you need to do, as I already have mentioned in my answer, is to wrap attributes in "user" key. Sorry, I don't familiar with Advanced REST client, but with an ajax call you can achieve this by providing params in data attribute
`$.ajax({ url: 'url', type: 'post', data: { user: { name: 'name', password: 'password' } } })`. But it's better to use [serialize() method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on form.